# How does MySQL MEMORY engine stores data in Heap?

Tags: mysql, memory, heap-memory

How exactly **MySQL MEMORY** engine stores data in **heap-memory**? How does it's internal(memory) look like?

Comment: Mysql is an open source software, so you can check out its code.

Comment: @Shadow, Then let's close SO, since everything's source is out there...